# Interpreting shell variables in bracket grep

Tags: shell, grep, brace-expansion

I have command like this :

```
grep ABC /tmp/dir{1,3,7}/file*.txt
```

It works perfectly fine, but I need extract constant with filename like this:

```
FILENAME="/tmp/dir{1,3,7}/file*.txt"
grep ABC $FILENAME
```

This does not work due the braces. 
How can I do it  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use eval for this, it's not necessary and not safe. In bash:

```
$ cat file1
abc
$ cat file2
dbf
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ x=( file{1,2} )
$ grep 'b' "${x[@]}"
file1:abc
file2:dbf
```

The [nullglob option](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion) causes the array to be empty if there are no file names that match the globbing pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This is one case in which [`eval`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) may be useful -and hopefully safe:

```
eval grep ABC "$FILENAME"
```

#### Test

```
$ seq 10 > a1
$ seq 10 > a2
$ seq 10 > a3
$ grep 5 a{1..3}
a1:5
a2:5
a3:5
```

But if we store in a variable it gets literal...

```
$ f=a{1..3}
$ echo $f
a{1..3}
$ echo "$f"
a{1..3}
$ grep 5 "$f"
grep: a{1..3}: No such file or directory
```

Hence the usage of `eval`:

```
$ eval echo "$f"
a1 a2 a3
$ eval grep 5 "$f"
a1:5
a2:5
a3:5
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `eval` to execute a command given as string.

**dir{1,2,3}** is converted to string after this command : `FILENAME="/tmp/dir{1,3,7}/file*.txt"`

run `eval grep ABC $FILENAME` to get the desired output

Comment: which is what I had answered minutes before : )

Comment: @fedorqui :  yeah,I noticed that after page refresh.. :)